# git clean exclude with regex

Tags: regex, git, git-clean

I'd like to find a regex-way of using `git clean`.

#### Without regex:

```
git clean -dfx --exclude=".idea/"
```

#### With regex (tried; not working):

```
git clean -dfx --exclude='(.*\/)*(\.idea\/.*)(.*)'
git clean -dfx --exclude="(.*\/)*(\.idea\/.*)(.*)"
git clean -dfx --exclude=r'(.*\/)*(\.idea\/.*)(.*)'
git clean -dfx --exclude=r"(.*\/)*(\.idea\/.*)(.*)"
```

How do you use `git clean` with regex?

Comment: You could always write a wrapper script with `grep`

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @VonC git version 1.9.5 (Apple Git-50.3)

Comment: @ssdecontrol Was wondering if git supports regex matcher internally

Comment: @VonC Situation seems to be the same in 2.1.2 (no regex-based excludes for clean), unless I am missing something. (I found this question because I was wondering the exact same thing as OP)

Comment: @Alderath do you see the same in 2.4.5?

Comment: Would you mind commenting the answer? Wether it works for you for example or not.

Answer (score 2):

`git clean` has no support for regular expressions.

---

**A workaround** would be something like this:

```
$ git clean -n | cut -f3 -d' ' | grep -v -E --color=never '<PATTERN>' | ifne git clean
```

---

**Breakdown** of things happening here:

- `git clean -n` produces a list of files that would be removed if `git clean` would be executed (you can use flags like `-d`, `-x` or `-X` here too)

  - `-n` dry-run (do not actually do anything)
- `cut -f3 -d' '` cuts the third field from those matches (delimited by an whitespace)

  - `-f3` third field
  - `-d' '` use whitespace as the delimiter
- `grep -v -E --color=never '<PATTERN>'`

  - `-v` invert the matches from grep
  - `-E` interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
  - `color=never` to prevent colored `grep` output to mess with the following commands (may be omitted)
  - `'<PATTERN>'` a regular expression
- `ifne git clean` will pipe the file list (if there are files) to `git clean`

  - `ifne` a utility function from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (installable via homebrew or other package managers)
  - `git clean` will take this list and clean the files (use `-n` first to make sure no files get removed that you did not expect)

*That is the magic of small command line programs each doing a simple specific task*

Comment: You can use `xargs` in place of `ifne`. I think you also need to pass `git clean -f` at the end to actually delete the files.